# Tell valgrind a value is actually initialized

Tags: c++, opengl, virtual-machine, valgrind

I have a false positive of valgrind telling me that a conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized values.

The code is like this:

```
//from GenerateTexture:
glGenTextures(1, (GLuint*)&texture_list[texture_pos]);
return texture_list[texture_pos++];

// Usage in another function
if(texture == 0)
    InitTexture(); // First line of function: texture = GenerateTexture();
if(texture == 0) // This is what valgrind complains about
    return;
```

I'm running the code in an Ubuntu VM with Windows host an have some earlier warnings about the OGL library so I assume that valgrind cannot handle the VM correctly. However I do know that the texture is initialized correctly and don't want to be bothered by valgrind on every use of `texture`.

How can I tell valgrind (maybe by code annotation) that this is a false positive? I know about the suppression file but then I'd need to add every function that uses texture to it, so I'm looking for a "cleaner" alternative.

Edit: As request an MCVE:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    const SDL_VideoInfo* video = SDL_GetVideoInfo( );

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 5 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 5 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 5 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );

    SDL_SetVideoMode( 800, 600, video->vfmt->BitsPerPixel, SDL_OPENGL );

    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    if(tex) std::cout << "1337";

    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind in VBox shows:

```
==2304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2304==    at 0xD97E21C: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94EB90: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0x400B49: main (test.cpp:46)
==2304==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2304==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2304==    by 0xD596F91: crAlloc (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD5A8688: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59840D: crNetConnectToServer (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59856D: crNetServerConnect (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94C4F8: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94A07E: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94B0EC: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAD09: crSPULoad (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAEC3: crSPULoadChain (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD283FB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD284318: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304== 
==2304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2304==    at 0xD5939E4: crHashIdPoolAllocId (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD593AF7: crHashtableAllocRegisterKey (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD97E207: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94EB90: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0x400B49: main (test.cpp:46)
==2304==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2304==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2304==    by 0xD596F91: crAlloc (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD5A8688: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59840D: crNetConnectToServer (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59856D: crNetServerConnect (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94C4F8: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94A07E: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94B0EC: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAD09: crSPULoad (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAEC3: crSPULoadChain (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD283FB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD284318: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304== 
==2304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2304==    at 0xD5939FC: crHashIdPoolAllocId (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD593AF7: crHashtableAllocRegisterKey (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD97E207: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94EB90: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0x400B49: main (test.cpp:46)
==2304==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2304==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2304==    by 0xD596F91: crAlloc (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD5A8688: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59840D: crNetConnectToServer (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59856D: crNetServerConnect (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94C4F8: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94A07E: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94B0EC: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAD09: crSPULoad (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAEC3: crSPULoadChain (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD283FB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD284318: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304== 
==2304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2304==    at 0xD593A27: crHashIdPoolAllocId (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD593AF7: crHashtableAllocRegisterKey (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD97E207: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94EB90: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0x400B49: main (test.cpp:46)
==2304==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2304==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2304==    by 0xD596F91: crAlloc (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD5A8688: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59840D: crNetConnectToServer (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59856D: crNetServerConnect (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94C4F8: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94A07E: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94B0EC: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAD09: crSPULoad (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAEC3: crSPULoadChain (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD283FB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD284318: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304== 
==2304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2304==    at 0xD593A29: crHashIdPoolAllocId (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD593AF7: crHashtableAllocRegisterKey (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD97E207: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94EB90: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0x400B49: main (test.cpp:46)
==2304==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2304==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2304==    by 0xD596F91: crAlloc (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD5A8688: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59840D: crNetConnectToServer (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59856D: crNetServerConnect (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94C4F8: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94A07E: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94B0EC: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAD09: crSPULoad (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAEC3: crSPULoadChain (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD283FB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD284318: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304== 
==2304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2304==    at 0xD593A30: crHashIdPoolAllocId (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD593AF7: crHashtableAllocRegisterKey (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD97E207: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94EB90: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0x400B49: main (test.cpp:46)
==2304==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2304==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2304==    by 0xD596F91: crAlloc (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD5A8688: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59840D: crNetConnectToServer (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59856D: crNetServerConnect (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94C4F8: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94A07E: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94B0EC: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAD09: crSPULoad (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAEC3: crSPULoadChain (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD283FB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD284318: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304== 
==2304== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2304==    at 0x400B52: main (test.cpp:47)
==2304==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2304==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2304==    by 0xD596F91: crAlloc (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD5A8688: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59840D: crNetConnectToServer (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD59856D: crNetServerConnect (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94C4F8: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94A07E: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD94B0EC: ??? (in /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.14/lib/VBoxOGLpackspu.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAD09: crSPULoad (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD2CAEC3: crSPULoadChain (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD283FB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
==2304==    by 0xD284318: ??? (in /usr/lib/VBoxOGL.so)
```

Comment: However downvoted this: Can you give at least a comment on why you did that? What is wrong with this question?

Comment: I didnt DV but questions should contain a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We can't tell from this post whether there is actually a bug in your code or not.  It seems to me that there probably is a bug otherwise you wouldn't have had to use that cast.

Comment: @M.M: That's right. However setting up a MCVE for this is maybe a quite lengthy example and probably only causes that behavior in a VM (maybe even with a specific version) So I pasted only the relevant part: Variable is assigned after call to glGenTextures but still "unset". I wasn't asking for finding a bug in the code but (if I am REALLY sure that there is no bug in MY code) for a way to tell valgrind about the definedness. So I expected an answer like the one from phd. And if I am misled an a MCVE is required, why can't one just post a comment? A DV only does not help anyone IMO.

Comment: The valgrind message could be correct, we can't tell from this. Your code probably violates the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @M.M Sure this is possible and I'll certainly double check that. But if it isn't (what is likely, as mentioned valgrind throws some more messages inside the OGL library itself) I need something to tell valgrind that. And this was the purpose of this question. But I'll update this later with a more complete example for reference.

Comment: The message says that the uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation, which `GLuint tex;` is not . It seems it refers to some internal workings of SDL as you can see from the valgrind trace.  So telling VG that your integer array is initialized wouldn't fix the problem ?

Comment: Yes it is the OGL internals, that is what I said in the initial question ;) I'd try to add a VALGRIND_MAKE_MEM_DEFINED after the assignment to tex so I hope to net get any further warnings on accessing it. Will see if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the valgrind memcheck request VALGRIND_MAKE_MEM_DEFINED.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs
and the file memcheck.h for more info.

Note however that assigning something to a variable is not a proof
that this variable is initialised:  if the value being assigned to the
variable is itself not (fully) initialised, then the 'undefinedness'
will be propagated.
So, before declaring the texture variable as defined, you should
double check that it is effectively properly initialised/defined.

You might e.g. first run with --track-origins=yes to have more info
about where the undefined value comes from.

Alternatively, you might interactively search the root cause
using valgrind+vgdb and gdb, checking the definedness of e.g.
texture_list.

See
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more info.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I wasn't able to find that using google. And the track-origins is a good tip to. I checked the case and GLuint=unsigned and the texture_list is an array of unsigneds. The original author of the code (it's in a OpenSource project) did not want to include the ogl headers in the header as it seems.